# Scrolling doesn't go all the way up jquery

Tags: jquery

As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/huJ95/ The scrolling stops like (5-10 pixels I believe) before the div starts (where the text is -> div starts, so the user would need to scroll up to see the beginning) Why is that? And how can I fix that? HTML/CSS in Jsfiddle ( I think is irrelavant).

JS:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("nav").on("click", "a", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it's pretty straightforward, you're not taking into account the height of the `nav`. So the content is at the top of the page, not underneath the nav. You need to subtract this from the calculation, eg:

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top - $('nav').outerHeight()}, 500);
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/huJ95/2/